# Php Utime faile error for Joomla (purity III) template

Tags: joomla

I installed the Purity-III template for Joomla (3.3.0) on my local machine and I get error message from time to time like in the picture below. 'From time to time' because when I refresh the page with the error message the error is gone (Before installing the temmplate I never got those error messages).

[image]

Any idea why this is happening and how to prevent?
(ps: I checked that that the access rights for files and folders are set in the proper way)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible that you do not have ownership of the file that is trying to be "touched". This is something that your server administration/hosting provider will have to sort out unless you're comfortable with SSH commands.

Also ensure that all folder are set to chmod **755** and files are **644**. To ensure this is the case, you can install an Joomla extension called [Admin Tools](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/site-protection/14087) which allows you to perform a bulk permission change.

Comment: thx for your comment. What I still dont understand that the error only happens from time to time? From your explenation I would conclude the error shopuld always happen (?)

Comment: Right you are however this is the first thing that springs to mind. It think it would be best if you contact the developers of the template/framework and maybe also the server host